# Can I make an reactjs axios request internally by https://localhost:1337?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, database, security, axios

I have two servers, which are both stayed at the same host but different port.
One is reactjs server hosted at port 3000.
Another one is database server with API interface hosted at port 1337.

I use Axios to make api request to the database, but it only works when I make call with Public IP address (for example: axios.get("http://215.128.23.16:1337/collection/"). When I change to localhost, it shows error. (shown in attached pictures)

What I want is to make API request internally, in order to restrict the IP address of accessing the database to only localhost connection.

Here are the steps I want to achieve: Client Side make a API call from browser -> Reactjs server receive the call -> Reactjs server send API request to database server internally (then I can restrict the IP access of accessing database to localhost) -> return result

Is this possible???

[image: The .ENV setting][image: The error request from the browser]

Comment: The actual error is not visible in your pictures

Comment: the request URL is localhost:1337 (as shown on picture), but I am not using the host computer.... thats why the connection turn RED..